# How to make buttons stretch so that they take whole width of the screen for react native?

Tags: css, react-native

I am trying to get three buttons to take equal width and stretch them so that they reach from one end of the screen to another. Here is my code:

```js
   <View style={styles.container}>

    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButton} underlayColor="white">
      <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>New</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>

    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButton} underlayColor="white">
      <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Search</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>

    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButton} underlayColor="white">
      <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Favorites</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    alignContent: 'stretch'
   },
   button: {
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: '#d6d7da',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: '#2196F3'
  },
  buttonText: {
   padding: 20,
   color: 'white'
  }
})
```

At the moment the buttons only cover 60% of the screen horizontally from left to right like this 
`|[button1][button2][button3]           |`
I am trying to do this 
`|[  button1 ][ . button2  ][  button3 ]|`
I have tried alignItems, alignContent and alignSelf to stretch but nothing works and there are blank spaces on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with flex. It should work

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButton} underlayColor="white" style={styles.button}>
    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>New</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>

<TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButton} underlayColor="white" style={styles.button}>
    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Search</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>

<TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButton} underlayColor="white" style={styles.button}> 
    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Favorites</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

```
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
    flex:1
   },
   button: {
    flex:1,
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: '#d6d7da',
    backgroundColor: '#2196F3'
  },
  buttonText: {
   padding: 20,
   color: 'white'
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks that did it. Is there a reason why you put flex: 1 on the container?

Comment: sorry, I put wrongly that flex:1 in the container.you can remove that flex:1 on the container. No issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`flex`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html), stretch 3 buttons equally with `flex: 1` on them:

```
button: {
  flex: 1,
  borderRadius: 4,
  borderWidth: 0.5,
  borderColor: '#d6d7da',
  backgroundColor: '#2196F3'
},
```

Note: `<TouchableHighlight />` is a special touchable with its own view. In your case you can make it works with `flex: 1` on `<TouchableHighlight />` directly but not its child.

For `<TouchableWithoutNativeFeedback />`, your code will be fine.